# Циклы в BeautifulSoup4 Python

Tags: html, python, парсер

Я запарсил сайт.

Ввожу эту команду, чтобы нашел определенную `<a>`

```
 soup.select('a[class="films_iconFrame"]')[0].attrs
```

Но как сделать так, чтобы он находил не один, а все `<a>` в html-коде

Пытался разными способами, но он выдавал одну и ту же`<a>` один раз(без цикла) или несколько раз одну(с циклом)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Находит все ссылки с этим классом

```
  a_list = soup.select('a[class="films_iconFrame"]')
  for a in a_list:
      print(a.attrs)
```